Clarification on Characteristics, Hyperbolic Conservation Laws, and Advection in PDEs
I am studying the linear advection equation:
$$
\partial_t u + a(x,t) \cdot \nabla_x u = 0, \quad u(x,0) = u_0(x), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^d, \, t \geq 0.
$$
An explicit solution is expressed as:
$$
u(x,t) = u_0(\Phi^{-t}(x)),
$$
where $\Phi_t(x_0)$ is the flow map associated with the ODE:
$$
\dot{x} = a(x,t), \quad x(0) = x_0.
$$
Here are the questions I am struggling with:

I know that for $x = \Phi_t(y)$,that $u(\Phi_t(y), t)$ is constant with time. Hence, it is easy to see that $u(x,t)$ is a solution to the advection equation, from here one can just map $x(t)$ to its initial condition to find its value $u(x,t) = u_0(\Phi^{-t}(x))$.

However, there is another way to do this. This is by calculating the time derivative of $\Phi^{-t}(x)$ with respect to $t$ to deduce that the formula $u(x,t) = u_0(\Phi^{-t}(x))$ indeed solves the linear advection equation. This I don't really find intuitive, how can I do this?

There is also some connection to hyperbolic conservation laws. The general form of a hyperbolic conservation law is given by:
$$
   \partial_t u + \nabla_x \cdot F(u) = 0,
   $$
where $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^d$ is the flux function.


Here, I am not sure what is exactly the connection between an advection equation and a hyperbolic conservation law. Using the chain rule, this equation can be rewritten as an advection equation with a velocity $\partial_{u}F = a(x,t,u(x,t))$ that depends on the solution of the PDE.
$$
\partial_t u + \partial_{u}F \cdot \nabla_x u = 0, \quad u(x,0) = u_0(x), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^d, \, t \geq 0.
$$

What is the difference between the advection equation and a hyperbolic conservation law?
Maybe, also relevant for my earlier question: what does it mean that the advection equation is a hyperbolic conservation law only if $\nabla_x \cdot a = 0$?, for example in the case for $F(u) = a \,u$.

Feel free to address any mistakes I made in my question.

Advection equation IS a hyperbolic conservation law, where the flux is linear w.r.t. $u$ like you said there. You can have a "nonlinear" advection equation of course, for example, Euler equations (which reduces to inviscid Burgers in 1d).
